# Scroll to a location on a page

Tags: html, css, navigation, scroll

I'm trying to move to a specific location on the page after a link is clicked. 
Here's my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

I want the page to jump to the writing section when the top writing link is clicked, and same thing for contact, similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ygcf/

But, when I sub in the appropriate ids, it's not working. Here's my html:

```
<div class="wrapper_nav_box">
    <div id="nav_menu" id="nav_box_1"><a href="#home_writing">WRITING  |</a></div>
```

and css:

```
.side_nav_contact {
        display:block;
        float:left;
        background:rgba(100,255,255,0);
        margin-top: 840px;
        width:200px;
        height: 50px;
}

#nav_box_l {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:247px;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 169px;
    margin-top: 0;
}


#nav_menu a:link{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}

#nav_menu a:hover{
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 100; 
        color:rgba (255,255,255,1);
        text-decoration: none; 
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.2em;
}
```

I suspect that this is because I'm using two ids (#nav_box_l and #nav_menu). #nav_menu is how I'm styling the links, while #nav_box_l contains "Writing." I tried combining but this doesn't work. Should I just use one? Does this technique not work if I want to jump to a class (.side_nav_content), not id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Writing" link:**

`home_writing` is currently a class, change that to an id `<div id="home_writing">` and it will work

**"About" link:**

You have set the link to `<a href="home_text"...` rather than `<a href="#home_text"`, stick the `#` in and that should work too

**"Contact" link:**

You don't have a div called `#contact`, which is what you are linking to, change the `<div class="home_contact">` to `<div id="contact">` and that one should work too

Comment: Hi Andy - OK, I still am not getting it. I changed home_writing to an id:

#home_writing {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(50,50,250,0);
    height: 800px;
    width: 980px;
    text-align: left;

}

<div class="nav_box_l" id="nav_menu" >
    <a href="#home_writing">WRITING  |</a></div>

And it's not jumping to the writing section...

Comment: Hi @Claire. This isn't an issue with your CSS file, its within the HTML itself. The reason it isn't working is because `home_writing` is a class at the minute. if you go to index.html and change line 143 (`<div class="home_writing">`) to `<div id="home_writing">` it will work

Answer (score 1):

An HTML element may only have one `id` and only one element may have that `id`. You can use a `class`for the styling.

```
.nav_box_l {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  width:247px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 169px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

<div id="nav_menu" class="nav_box_1">...</div>
```